# mql4 Expert Advisor - OnTick() does not do anything in [ Strategy Tester ]

Tags: mql4

Part of the code:

```
int OnInit()
{   
    Print( "SL mover started" );

    return( INIT_SUCCEEDED );
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert tick function                                             |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnTick()
{   
     modifySLs();
}

void modifySLs()
{
     int i, total = OrdersTotal();

     Alert( total );

     Print( "modify runs" );

     for( i = 0; i <  total; i++ ) {

          modifySLIfNeededForSelectedOrder( i );
     }
}
```

Why `OnTick()` does not run?

It does not print any message in the log, nor `Alert()` function gets called when I run in Strategy Tester. `OnInit()` function works - prints in the log "SL mover started".

Comment: @Darius-v How did the below proposed solution work for your Strategy Tester experiments?

Answer (score 0):

### MQL4 Documentation is explicit on this:

> `Alert()` function does not work in the Strategy Tester.

So better remove it.

> `Print()` function does not work during optimization in the Strategy Tester.

So, unless your Strategy Tester has genetic optimisation check-box on, this ought create no issues.

If in doubts about indeed "entering" the `OnTick()` code-block, may equip it with a non-blocking smart informer:

```
int aGlobatTickCOUNTER = 0;
void OnTick()
{
     Comment( "[OnTick()].INF::", ++aGlobalTickCOUNTER );

     modifySLs();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It runs. Weather you think it does not execute, it executes. it works. `Ontick()` function is running once when the value is changed in last floating point according to the charts.
But the problem is you can't see it is working because Stratergy tester not allows `Alerts()` and `print()` functions. It only allow to execute functions like `OrderSend()`,`OrderClose()`,`Ordermodify()` and etc.

Comment: This is not true - The strategy tester logs `Print()`-calls to the log, which can be seen in the journal. Its just the problem with `onTick()` - This is the reason why the OP has this valid question.

Comment: I just had the same problem. But I found out that my OnTick method was declared as "int OnTick()". When I have changed it to "void OnTick()" it started to work.